# CapacitorJS, Can not connect to backend API Android using but works on web

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I am build hybrid app using capacitor.js as runtime,
but  i can not conncect to the backend at all.
the following code works in web, android device chrome browser but not on the generated app.

```
async  function  checkConnection2(){
tts.value = await axios.get('http://192.168.8.101:8000/api/tts');
tts.value =tts.value.data
console.log(tts.value)

};
```

What i have already tried
I have added `usesCleartextTraffic` in my android manifest

Comment: logs? error messages?

Comment: @johnborges sorry using remote webView debugger in Chrome I see the error was 419. Now solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is not working because the web does sent CSRF token along with a post request ,but the android app didn't.
Excluding my API URIs in CSRF verification solved the problem.